# Question about càdlàg function of a stochastic process which is continuous in probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Consider the following function $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f(t,x)$ is càdlàg in $t$.

I am interested in the following quantity:

$f(t,X_{t-})-f^-(t,X_{t-})$

for a martingale $X$ which is continuous in probability. Now suppose $\Delta X_t \neq 0$ for a $t$, why is then the quantity above zero? We know that $f=f^-$ for all but countably many times, since it is càdlàg.